# REGEX Help for Coldfusion - In a URL, removing the ? And everything after

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm looking for some REGEX help
Given the following URL: http://news.cnet.com/8301-13924_3-10315534-64.html?part=rss&subj=news&tag=2547-1_3-0-20

What is the REGEX to obtain the following:

http://news.cnet.com/8301-13924_3-10315534-64.html

Thus removing the ? and everything after it

Thanks, B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression will do the trick:

> `^([^?]+)`

Just take the second capture group from the match (the first capture group is always the original string itself if it matched).

Answer (score 10):

You can certainly use a regex for this, but it would be more efficient to use

`listfirst(theurl, '?')`

which finds the first part of a list delimited by question marks.

Comment: +1 for a nice simple solution. The list*() functions in CF can be very powerful when used in non-obvious ways.

Comment: I agree, I always look to list functions before regex.

Answer (score 3):

In ColdFusion you could use regex replace:

```
myURL = REReplace(myURL,"\?.*$","")
```

That would leave you with everything before the question mark.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben Doom: If I'm not mistaken, the #url# variable is a complex object and cannot be treated as a string or list. The way I go about getting everything before the query string is:

```
<cfset myURL = "http://" & #cgi.HTTP_HOST# & #cgi.SCRIPT_NAME# />
```

Comment: Obviously, I didn't mean to attempt this op on the url scope.  I unthinkingly used 'url' to mean a variable holding the URL in question.

Comment: Yeah, you know it occurred to me after I wrote my answer that you were referring to a variable with the url stored in it rather than the scope itself. Great answer though, I wouldn't have thought of using that technique.